# Cannot filter C-related jobs in Careers

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Did I miss something, or is it not possible to effectively filter job offers in Careers related to C programming?

There is a tag system which seems similar to the standard Stack Overflow website, but all it seems to do is add the "c" word to the filter, which does not ensure that filtered results actually contain the `c` tag.

`c++`, for instance, already works much better, but `c` seems to match almost every job offer, since they invariably contain at least one word containing the letter C...

Comment: This is also a problem on Chat.SO. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've adjusted the search algorithm to help with this. [Check out the `c` tag now.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c)

We were discarding single-letter search terms and tags, so a search for `c` was treated as an empty search. Now it properly filters down to just posts that contain `c`.

I've also increased the importance of tags in the search results, which should help bump actual C jobs above Objective-C and the like.

Comment: Indeed, for me the first offer which does not contain the `c` tag only appears at the end of the second page, and it contains `objective-c` nevertheless. Couldn't find any jobs for the B and D programming languages though, but I believe it's not due to the search algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a shortcoming with the way we are currently indexing jobs in elastic search. As a temporary workaround, you could try searching for "c/c++", which will give you slightly better (though not great) search results.